# Numpy - Count the rows in matrix for which column is the minimum?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

So if I have a matrix like this:

```
[ 6 9 4 7]
[ 1 2 3 4]
[ 3 5 9 8] 
[ 5 7 2 4]
```

I want to know how many times the first column is the minimum. For example, here the answer would be `2`, where the 2nd and 3rd row have column 1 as the minimum. I know we can find the minimum using `matrix.min(axis=1)` from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29301904/extracting-minimum-values-per-row-using-numpy), and I think we can use [`numpy.sum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) to count the number of rows... but how would I actually know from which column the minimum came from? I there some simple way to accomplish this in numpy?

Comment: Consider starting with [argmin](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html#numpy.argmin).

Comment: @sascha Thank you! Thats exactly the starting point that I needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if it helps anyone else, due to the `argmin` suggestion, came up with this approach that works for the first column:

```
np.count_nonzero(np.argmin(matrix,axis=1))
```

Not sure about the performance of this method over large matrices or anything like that however.. Of course, this doesn't work for anything but checking minimums on the first column